# debugging jQuery snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I was trying to take a working jQuery snippet (it's an example to another SO answer) and improve it.

The original snippet can show a good and a bad way of doing something, by having to comment/un-comment some code. I tried to modify the HTML and the JS so that both examples can be run independently, without modifying JS code (by basically cloning sample HTML into a copy with different IDs).

Original JSFiddle worked fine: http://jsfiddle.net/thangchung/LVAaV/

My "improved" version doesn't seem to work at all: http://jsfiddle.net/dvkdvk/C2YBE/19/

(doesn't work means that when you push any button, nothing happens).

I don't know how to debug it with jQuery (with regular JS I would just sprinkle `alert()` everywhere). I ran "JSHint" on JSFiddle and it was OK.

Comment: With jQuery you can also sprinkle `alerts` and `console.logs` everywhere.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid - EVen the very first alert doesn't work. I suspect there's something wrong in my selectors.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid merely sprinkling alerts and console.log() won't make debugging very easy. The script needs to be properly debugged by inserting break points at important positions.

Comment: fiddle not working simply because you didn't select to load jQuery in top left `frameworks`. First clue to problem is in error thrown in console `$ is not defined`

Comment: @TalhaMasood, thanks, I know that. I was merely correcting the OP when he stated 'with regular JS I would just sprinkle alert() everywhere'. I was just saying that he can still do that with jQuery if he so wished.

Comment: @charlietfl - Oh. Now I feel dumb. Make that an answer! It works now.

Comment: @DVK: Easy mistake to make. Done it myself a few times. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid. Ha! You should try to elaborate more when ever making a point. I got an impression that you were suggesting that the script should be debugged by sprinkling alerts() and console.log(). This in my opinion is not the best way when you can insert break points to debug JavaScript and see the execution at each step.

Comment: @TalhaMasood, yes, maybe I should elaborate more - my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new fiddle did not select a library. Select it from the left side of the form and click Run.

I found this by using Firebug's script debugger in Firefox. Turn on script debugging with the developer tools in your browser of choice. Otherwise, Javascript fails silently. You can then set breakpoints, look at variables, etc. That is much more efficient than using Alerts and console logs (although they do have their place).

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is with your JSFIDDLE setup. On the left hand side of the page, make sure you include the jQuery library and select `onDomReady` from the frameworks and extensions panel.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this script in FireFox, Firebug. The scrips runs fine here with me. Kindly see the environment in which you are trying to run this script.